# Extend trait only for specific associated type

Tags: rust

I'm looking to extend the `Iterator` trait but only for a specific associated type `type Item = f64;`:

```rust
trait IteratorExt: Iterator {
    fn minmax(mut self) -> (f64, f64)
    where Self::Item: f64  // <- Not allowed! Needs to be a trait.
    {
        let mut min = f64::NAN;
        let mut max = f64::NAN;
        for value in self {
            min = f64::min(min, *value);
            max = f64::max(max, *value);
        }
        (min, max)
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator> IteratorExt for I {}
```

And expect to use it like this:

```rust
assert_eq!([2, 3, 1].iter().minmax(), (1, 3));
```

One way to solve it would be to create yet another trait `Float` to represent a float and then implement it for `f64`. That trait would expose the `NAN` associated const as well as would extend `PartialOrd` which would allow me to perform the comparison. With such trait in presence, I could modify the iterator code above to read `where Self::Item: Float`. This seems relatively verbose though and I wonder if there's a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define your trait only for `Iterators` over  `f64`, you can express it like this:

```
trait IteratorExt: Iterator<Item = f64> {
    fn minmax(&mut self) -> (f64, f64) {
        let mut min = f64::NAN;
        let mut max = f64::NAN;
        for value in self {
            min = f64::min(min, value);
            max = f64::max(max, value);
        }
        (min, max)
    }
}
```

If, as your actual code seems to be trying, you want the trait to be valid for all iterators, but want the `minmax` method to be only available for iterators over `f64`, you can put the same constraint on the method itself:

```
trait IteratorExt: Iterator {
    fn minmax(&mut self) -> (f64, f64)
    where
        Self: Iterator<Item = f64>,
    {
        let mut min = f64::NAN;
        let mut max = f64::NAN;
        for value in self {
            min = f64::min(min, value);
            max = f64::max(max, value);
        }
        (min, max)
    }
}
```

Comment: That does it. Wasn't aware of this syntax for specifying associated type. Thanks!